# Interface not defined while using dev server

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

I created a project with vite v5 by using the react-ts template.

While running the app with: `pnpm dev`, the following error appears:

```
App.tsx:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: CharacterConnectionStatus is not defined
    at App.tsx:9:22
```

My `App.tsx` file looks like this:

```
const character: Character = {
  id: "1",
  username: "john_doe",
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  birthday: "1990-01-01",
  description: "A description of John Doe.",
  avatarURI: "https://placehold.co/400x400",
  connection_status: CharacterConnectionStatus.ONLINE,
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div
      id="app"
      className="h-screen w-screen bg-base-100 text-accent-content antialiased"
    >
      <div className="container mx-auto p-6">{JSON.stringify(character)}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have a `src/types/index.d.ts` file that contains the `Character` interface as well as the `CharacterConnectionStatus` enum:

```
// Enums

enum CharacterConnectionStatus {
  ONLINE = "online",
  OFFLINE = "offline",
  AWAY = "away",
}

// Interfaces

interface Character {
  id: string;
  username: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  birthday: string;
  description: string;
  avatarURI: string;
  connection_status: CharacterConnectionStatus;
}
```

The code works just fine if I set the `connection_status` field as optional inside the interface:

```
interface Character {
  // all the other fields
  connection_status?: CharacterConnectionStatus;
}
```

In order to create the object with no `connection_status` field on my App component:

```
const character: Character = {
  id: "1",
  username: "john_doe",
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  birthday: "1990-01-01",
  description: "A description of John Doe.",
  avatarURI: "https://placehold.co/400x400",
};
```

Which allows me to know that the project is capable of resolving the `Character` interface, but not the enum, but both of them are in the exact same file.

In order for the index.d.ts to work, I added the following code to my `tsconfig.json` file:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* a bunch of config */
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "/src/types"
  }
}
```

Is there any visible error on this approach for the server not to resolve the `CharacterConnectionStatus` enum?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm surprised you don't see a type-checking error similar to this: `'CharacterConnectionStatus' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`. How are you type-checking your code before running it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may not want to use enums in your ts application. [Read more on here](https://dev.to/ivanzm123/dont-use-enums-in-typescript-they-are-very-dangerous-57bh)

Rename `src/types/index.d.ts` to `src/types/index.ts`

Make sure you are exporting `CharacterConnectionStatus` and `Character` as well.

```
export const CHARACTER_CONNECTION_STATUS = {
  ONLINE: "online",
  OFFLINE: "offline",
  AWAY: "away",
} as const;

type CharacterConnectionStatus = keyof typeof CHARACTER_CONNECTION_STATUS;


export interface Character {
  id: string;
  username: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  birthday: string;
  description: string;
  avatarURI: string;
  connection_status: CharacterConnectionStatus;
}
```

Make sure to import `CHARACTER_CONNECTION_STATUS` and `Character` in `App.tsx`

```
const character: Character = {
  id: "1",
  username: "john_doe",
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  birthday: "1990-01-01",
  description: "A description of John Doe.",
  avatarURI: "https://placehold.co/400x400",
  connection_status: CHARACTER_CONNECTION_STATUS.ONLINE,
};
```

Comment: In [the code shown](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77923611/2), `CHARACTER_CONNECTION_STATUS` is a _value_ (not a _type_), so the type of the field `connection_status` in the interface `Character` should be `typeof CHARACTER_CONNECTION_STATUS[keyof typeof CHARACTER_CONNECTION_STATUS]`.

Comment: I love taht reading that you linked and it fixed my problem so, thank a lot for this!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot declare enums in a `.d.ts` file, since it will have a compiled output while interfaces and types will not.

The closest you can have in a `.d.ts` file is a type that restricts string constants, like:

```
type CharacterConnectionStatus = 'ONLINE' | 'OFFLINE' | 'AWAY';
```

This does restrict the possible values, but you cannot call them as constants like you could with enums. If you do want to keep using constants, then you should export those types from a `.ts` file and import them whenever you need them.